# How to use Eslint formatting with Intellij IDEA standard reformatting (Ctrl+Alt+L)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ide, eslint, autoformatting

We have project with both Java and Javascript code, so we cannot use `Reformat code` before commit option, because it breaks Javascript files style. But it is still very usefull for Java code.

We try to use Javascript Standard Style for both Eslint and IDEA Javacript Code Style configuration, but this is not enough because we cannot use JSX formatting rules (for break jsx attribute on new line, for example)

Is there way to format all Java and Javascript by one hot key? 
And also do it before commit?

Comment: Have you tried to import ESLint rules into IDEA code style: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eslint.html#ws_js_linters_eslint_import_code_style_from_eslint ?

Comment: Yes, but rules for JSX do not have corresponding options in IDEA Code Style

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.